# graph of moving object

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

let us consider following three  picture  grouped as  in one picture
[image]

suppose that we have following  problem:
during the  $1$ hour,biker was moving around station $A$ and during this  $1$,he did not go further then $10KM$ from station A ,question is:  from given  three graph,which one could be graph ,which describes  distance passed by  biker as depend on parameter time $t$

clearly  second  one(სურათი ||,სურათი(georgian) means picture,კმ-km(distance ))  describes because  during $1$ hour,biker has not moved more then $10$ km from station $A$,but what about  first and third one?this problem we can represent as a biker moving way as a  circle with center  on origin of coordinate  axes and  radius $10$,answer says that  second and third one can be graph which describes movement of biker,but i am surprise,because at $1$  he reached more  then $10$ from $A$,while  first picture we should determine where  sum of length of triangles is more then $10$,but on the other hand,one picture first,he has not gone more then $10$ point on $S$ axis,please help me

Comment: There's some ambiguity here which may be due to the translation, but one might understand what you say as either he did not do more than 10km total distance or he did not go farther than 10km from station A. The latter could be done while riding more than 10km in total distance.

Comment: did not go further then $10$KM from station $A$

Comment: i have updated  @Raskolnikov please see

Comment: It's not clear what $S$ represents to me. I thought from your description initially that you meant it was the total distance travelled (like on the mileage clock) up to that point, but then in the first picture it decreased!

Comment: S represent distance,t time

Comment: Does $S$ represent (a) distance *from the station* or (b) distance travelled in any direction by the biker?  If it is (a), graphs 1 and 2 are possible since the biker's distance to the station does not exceed 10. If it is (b), then graph 1 is invalid since distance cannot decrease, and graphs 2 and 3 are both possible.